# Не загружается первый кадр видео на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, видео

Есть сайт со страницей с видео роликами https://ci41159.tw1.ru/video/ , проблема в том, что на мобильных устройствах первый кадр видео не грузится.
Отображается только кнопка play.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Похоже, что из-за кодеков. У меня в Chrome 109 нормально отображается и проигрывается только четвёртое видео (здесь кодек указан в атрибуте правильно). Первые три ролика видит, как аудио (у них одинаковый кодек и он не совпадает с тем, что указано в атрибутах). В плеере VLC всё норм (оттуда и инфа про кодеки)

Comment: На мобиле с эппл работает все видео, на 11 андроиде тоже все видео работают